# MPMoviePlayerViewController method click on pause

Tags: iphone, methods, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie

I'm using MPMoviePlayerViewController and I want to know if there is a method that can tell me when the user clicks on the Pause button for the video, like an observer?

Answer (score 0):

You should use MPMoviePlayerController instead :

> Movie Player Notifications
>   The MPMoviePlayerController class generates numerous notifications to keep your application informed about the state of movie playback. In addition to being notified when playback finishes, interested clients can be notified in the following situations:
>
> - **When the movie player begins playing, is paused, or begins seeking forward or backward**
> - When the scaling mode of the movie changes
> - When the movie enters or exits fullscreen mode
> - When the load state for network-based movies changes
> - When meta information about the movie itself becomes available
> - For more information, see the Notifications section in this document.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that i have to use MPMoviePlayerViewController. There is any method for this controller?

Comment: Because i just want for the new version of ipad.

Comment: Hi, what notification i have to use to know that the user click on pause, using the MPMoviePlayerController. Thanks

Comment: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help. Don't forget to accept answers (checkmark tick on the left side of an answer)